# What are the applications of array rotations?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, rotation

I see these programming questions everywhere:

> - Find an element in a sorted rotated integer array.
> - A sorted array has been rotated r times to the left. Find r in least possible time.
> - Rotate an array by k positions in place (without using extra memory)
> - And so on....

My question is, why would someone do that? Is there a real algorithm that requires linear array rotation? What are some practical uses of array rotations?

Comment: The concept of rotation pops up in a few places, but it's usually implemented more cleverly (cf. ring buffers) because really rotating array elements takes linear time when you need it to take constant time.

Comment: This is such a broad question. There are, probably, thousand reasons... Simple example: rotation of array that is coordinates of a 2D space vector is a mirror transformation around (1,1) axis.

Comment: I remember having a project that basically was array manipulation since in order to create a mirror image or rotate an image, you have to change indexes and to do so requires array manipulation. Even though these questions may seem pointless, there real goal is create a way of thinking and solving problems and they probably have real world applications!

Comment: I think RUBIX CUBE rotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are exercises? It's like the problems that are given in school. They aren't real-world problems. They are problems that should teach you something. And all your three examples are interesting.

There are already too many programmers that aren't able to think 10 minutes before writing (bad) code. These problems require you to think.

I'll add that there are various programmers (me included) that love good complex problems. Complex math+programming problems are like sudoku, but better, because after doing sudoku you haven't learned anything new (you have only exercised your brain), while after doing a complex problem sometimes you have learned something (at least how to make your code totally unreadable :-) ) and surely you have exercised your brain. There are even sites with hundred of problems, like [spoj](http://www.spoj.com/).

Comment: Seems like a pretty useless exercise for me.

Comment: @OleksiyDobrodum So you are able to solve all three of them? I think I can't do any of them in less than 1h each.

Comment: @OleksiyDobrodum why useless? It helps people to develop their computational thinking and it works well

Comment: @OleksiyDobrodum Determining whether and where two planes intersect is a very useless task without any context, but people still learn a lot about linear algebra while doing it...

Answer (score 0):

well it's a way to a deep understanding, is it? i you train hard, when you play is easier, and i'm totally sure that in so context, this would be useful!.